# convert a convex path to triangle list

Tags: c++, opengl

What is the best way to convert a convex path (it is describing in points set) to a list of triangles to be used in opengl render. I think the best stuff is sample code or demo :) thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to a set of drawn lines or to a filled in polygon that you want to draw?

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework like cocos2d/cocos2d-x/libgdx to do the drawing?

Comment: er, I want to fill it, I dont know the libgdx ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for one of the many "convert a polygon to a series of triangles" solutions:

Maybe something in one of these will help:

- [Ear Clipping](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf)
- [List item](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/polygon-triang.pdf)
- [poly2tri](https://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/) (with source code)

If you are trying to understand the concepts, the first two are a good place to start.
If you need an implementation, start with the third.

Was this helpful?

Comment: Sorry for my description, I need fill a convex path, not line link its.

Comment: @user3117740 I added several references.

Answer (score 0):

If your polygon is really convex and not concave you can just draw it as a triangle fan. That is guaranteed to work.

Here is a alternative recursive algorithm that I wrote a few years ago. It also triangulates a concave polygon and on average generates a much nicer triangulation (e.g. less sliver polygons):

```
void ConcaveTesselator (unsigned a_NumVertices)
{
  unsigned left[32];     // enough space for 2^32 recursions:
  unsigned right[32];    
  unsigned stacktop = 0;

  // prepare stack:
  left[0]  = 0;
  right[0] = a_NumVertices-1;
  stacktop = 1;

  while (stacktop)
  {
    unsigned l,r,m;

    // pop current interval from the stack and subdivide:
    stacktop--;
    l = left[stacktop];
    r = right[stacktop];
    m = (l+r)>>1;

    // replace this with your triangle drawing function
    // or store the indices l,m,r and draw the triangles 
    // as a triangle list later:

    DrawTriangleWithIndices (l,m,r);

    // recursive subdivide:
    if (m-l > 1) 
    { 
      left[stacktop]  = l; 
      right[stacktop] = m; 
      stacktop++; 
    } 
    if (r-m > 1) 
    { 
      left[stacktop]  = m; 
      right[stacktop] = r; 
      stacktop++; 
    }
  }
}
```